# Не читается .txt на Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, txt

Если путь к текстовому файлу написать полностью вручную, он читается и выводит результат.

```
file = open("C:/Users/zerg0_000/Desktop/4 Training's/Telegram_bot/COB/COB1.txt",
            "r", encoding= "UTF-8")
txt = file.read()
print(txt)
```

Если путь к текстовому файлу содержит форматированные элементы (где `name = 'COB', id_ = 1`), результата нет.

```
file = open(f"C:/Users/zerg0_000/Desktop/4 Training's/Telegram_bot/{name}/{name}{str(id_)}.txt",
            "r", encoding= "UTF-8")
txt = file.read()
print(txt)
```

Подскажите, почему это может происходить и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Используйте модуль `pathlib`

Comment: "почему это может происходить"  У тебя версия Python какая? f-strings есть только в Python 3.6 и далее.

Comment: Верся Python 3.8...

Comment: Сейчас попробую модуль `pathlib`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все работает правильно:

```
file = open(f"D:/_Qt/__Qt/Test/4 Training's/Telegram_bot/COB/COB1.txt",
            "r", encoding= "UTF-8")
txt = file.read()
file.close()
print("1", txt)


name = 'COB'
id_ = 1

file = open(f"D:/_Qt/__Qt/Test/4 Training's/Telegram_bot/{name}/{name}{str(id_)}.txt",
            "r", encoding= "UTF-8")
txt = file.read()
file.close()
print("2", txt)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Так:

```
file = open(f"C:/Users/zerg0_000/Desktop/4 Training's/Telegram_bot/%s/%s%d.txt" % (name,name,id_),
            "r", encoding= "UTF-8")
txt = file.read()
file.close()
print(txt)
```

Comment: Все равно, файл не читается. Я работаю над ботом Telegram PyCharm, сделал так чтобы изначально, вывод делался в консоль, а потом в виде сообщения в чат. Текстовый документ содержит информацию, но при функции **file.read()** ничего не выводит и пишет `ApiException('A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:\n[b\'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message text is empty"}\']')
` , так еще и через модуль Pickle выдает ошибку.

Comment: Исключение происходит из-за того что текст сообщения пустой. Возможно что файл пустой.